# Disabled is not considered an HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angular, testing, chai

I have this button in html

```html
 const dom = new JSDOM(`
<button id="ref_button" type="submit" [disabled]="editForm.form.invalid || isSaving" class="btn btn-primary">`)
```

I am testing it like this using Chai:

```html
 dom.window.document.getElementById("ref_button").should.have.attr('type');
```

And it works perfectly.
 But if I want to test the same way the **disabled** attribute the test doesn't work:

```html
  dom.window.document.getElementById("ref_button").should.have.attr('[disabled]');
```

Itt always says that the attribute exists. This is not normal, cause it should not exist according to teh condition (when I fill the form with valid data).

Am I doing something wrong in Chai?

Comment: `But if I want to test the same way` as in?

Comment: I edited teh question

Answer (score 1):

I don't know more about Chai, but just gone through it try below one

```
prop() or property()

dom.window.document.getElementById("ref_button").should.have.prop('disabled');
```

or

```
dom.window.document.getElementById("ref_button").should.have.property('disabled');
```

**Updated snippet**

Can you try like below

```
is()

dom.window.document.getElementById("ref_button").is('[disabled]')).toBe(true)
```

Above one may work, please try it. If not, try below one also

```
hasAttr() or hasAttribute()

dom.window.document.getElementById("ref_button").hasAttribute('disabled')
```

Comment: The same result

Comment: Mybe you need to refer to chai doc http://www.chaijs.com/guide/styles/ , cause I think you are using Jasmine. These methods do not exist in chai

Comment: Oh, and something, since it works for anotehr attribute this means that this is the right way to do it! But maybe it is not recognising the vhange in this attribute value, when it is null and when true regarding the data input in the form.

Comment: @Tester :-) Yeah I am referring the Chai documentation only. I have been letting you know what I understood from there. You are saying **It works for another attribute...!!!** does any line in my answer became helpful for you? and 1 year back I wrote test cases using **Protractor** I am now entirely into development :-)

Comment: No If you read my question, I say that what I do works for anotehr attribute. But your code is more like Jasmine